# Migrating Spartacus SAP Commerce Cloud 2011

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am migrating Spartacus on SAP commerce cloud 2011 and we do not have custom commercewebservice extension, enabling this OOB extension giving error on server start

Comment: Please provide more details like what kind of error you get

Comment: This issue was because of conflicting with other extension. Is fixed now. Thanks for responding